# Retrieving a long path from "\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Progra~1"

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm writing a ProcessExplorer-like tool that shows all open files in the system.
Calling the `NtQueryObject(,ObjectNameInformation,,,)` gives me a path that looks like `\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt`, so it is an NT device path that sometimes has shortened segments (ADMINI~1 in this case).

I don't really need to convert this path to a "standard" one (like `C:\Users`), but I need to expand it to a long form, so it should look like `\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt`. Besides, converting a device path to a standard one won't even be possible if the volume doesn't have a mountpoint.

I need a solution that works from Windows XP onwards.

Unfortunately, the most obvious method - using the GetLongPathNameW function doesn't work with a path like this, it returns a ERROR_INVALID_NAME for a path like this.

I tried different path prefixes: `\\?\`, `\\.\`, `\??\`, `\\.\GLOBALROOT\` - none of this helped.
FindFirstFileW also doesn't accept a path like this on Vista.
It's strange, because the CreateFile function works with a `\Device\HarddiskVolume` path just fine.

Also I found, that if I remove the Device word from the path, making it `\\.\HarddiskVolume1\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt`, the GetLongPathNameW actually returns a correct long path. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Windows XP/Vista.

I'd like to know if there is another method, that will work on Windows XP too.

Comment: for what you need convert to long path ? short also valid and can be used. you can use `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileNormalizedNameInformation` for get long, normalized name. this is the best way. but not on xp (exist sense still support xp ?) possible query `FileInternalInformation` and then try open file by it (id) (if of course you can open file again) and query new file handle for `FileNameInformation`. in any case you need query for `FileNameInformation` just after `NtQueryObject` for separate device name and file name.

Comment: I just want to show user the full path of opened files, because it's easier to understand than `ADMINI~1`. Surprisingly enough, Win XP is still used by a lot of users, especially on older hardware, so I'd like to support it for a while.

Comment: As for opening files, in some cases it is not possible, because a file could be used by another process without a FILE_SHARE_READ flag.

Comment: *to show user the full path of opened files* - i think that need show for user as is, without convert to long path. because in this case you show also and path by which file was open (short or long) and this is some info. if you normalize path - this info will be lost